# Wifi wont work on desktop, but works on laptop

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, drivers

I moved from one location to another location.

suddenly I cant get any wifi to connect to.
when opening the Wi-Fi interface "could not find any wifi-networks"
my laptop, has wifi, and is connected as normal. there are 3 wifis nearby, but my desktop wont show any of them.

when enabling wifi hotspot on my laptop, it appears in the wifi overview on my desktop.
i can connect to the hotspot my laptop created.

but I cant see or connect to the wifi I'm connected to on my laptop or my phone.

desktop:
intel(r) wifi 6 ax200 160mhz driver
ASUS ROG Strix B550-F GAMING (WI-FI)

here are some details about the wifi the laptop is connected to:

```
Name                   : Wi-Fi
Description            : Realtek 8822CE Wireless LAN 802.11ac PCI-E NIC
GUID                   : 8b5decb9-2cf4-4c64-ae4b-07d111bc05e1
Physical address       : 70:66:55:26:a0:99
State                  : connected
SSID                   : NAME HERE
BSSID                  : 34:21:09:2c:25:9e
Network type           : Infrastructure
Radio type             : 802.11n
Authentication         : WPA2-Personal
Cipher                 : CCMP
Connection mode        : Auto Connect
Channel                : 1
Receive rate (Mbps)    : 28.9
Transmit rate (Mbps)   : 28.9
Signal                 : 38%
```

what I've tried:

- reset internet settings
- reset dns
- uninstall driver
- install driver
- ofc turning pc on and off.

what it looks like on laptop: https://prnt.sc/1ism3gi
on desktop: https://prnt.sc/1islm9o

[image: laptop]

desktop: (please ignore the 1 connection, that's my laptop).
[image: desktop]

i do now have access to router, cause thats the landlord domain.

i just find it strange that it works on laptop and phone, but not on the desktop. and strange that neighboors wifis not showing up either :|

Comment: We need more information about the router, not the PC itself. If you're not seeing your SSID in the list of available networks then it's probably something external to the PC you're using. Did you move service with your ISP? Is the router plugged in? Can you reach the admin login screen and get to the settings?

Comment: @hunsbct i do not have access to router, cause thats the landlord domain. i just find it strange that it works on laptop and phone, but not on the desktop. and strange that neighboors wifis not showing up either :|

Comment: Your screenshots are inaccessible.  You should upload them using the feature provided by the editor.

Comment: works fine by me, i uploaded them in the editor too now @Ramhound

Answer (score 0):

This could be several issues. But before all else, restart your computer!!

It’s possible that the WiFi antenna is not facing a router. I have had an issue with my metal case where I have needed to get an external top mounted antenna(like old tv’s) to get a good signal because my case blocks it.

If rotating your pc towards the closest router doesn’t help, try unplugging and re plugging in your WiFi card. It’s possible it got jostled when moved.

Also, to aid in troubleshooting, consider returning it to its original location temporarily to see if it works like it used to. If it does, then you know that the issue wasn’t caused by moving it.

I noticed you messed around with windows drivers too. Once I caused weird WiFi errors doing this recently and had to reinstall windows to fix it. If all the above fails, maybe try booting a live Linux USB stick and see if the WiFi works on Linux. If it does, the solution may be to reinstall windows.

Ideally you want to get it to a functional state, by moving it back or putting a router close to it temporarily, and change one variable at a time until you find what breaks.

Good luck!